# when to use decorator and decorator factory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, factory, python-decorators

This gets bit of confusing with decorator takes no argument while decorator factory takes argument and still decorates a function

It would be helpful when to use when description .

Edit: 
Confusion is over an example:

```
def before_run(func):
    print "hello from before run"
    def handle_arg(a,b):
        if(a>0):
            a= 100
        return func(a,b)

    return handle_arg

@before_run
def running_func(a,b):
    print "a",a,"b", b
    return a+b
```

Edit: Is there a way to do this using decorator factory by adding logging option(true or false)?

Comment: You answered it yourself already. A decorator that takes arguments is a decorator factory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but i not able to make a case scenario where it would fit perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Then it is unclear to me what you are asking here. [some decorators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) take arguments, while [others don't](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry for not being clear, i am looking for a distinguish factor between decorator and decorator factory. Also made an edit in question.

Comment: Still not clear. Why would you want to complicate your decorator by wrapping it in a factory? What arguments does it require?

Comment: You can always make it a decorator factory without arguments, but you wouldn't want to because that just complicates things.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the most common scenario i saw about factory was passing true or false for logging arguments/output .

Comment: @MartijnPieters "@functools.wraps" is used in factory right ?

Comment: `@functools.wraps(f)` produces a decorator callable, which is then used to actually decorate the function. So it is *itself* a factory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71577/discussion-between-igaurav-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: why print "hello from before run"is invoked without calling anything at all ?

Comment: its says by itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A decorator *factory* is just a callable that produces the actual decorator. It is used to make it possible to 'configure' a decorator.

So instead of:

```
@decorator
def decorated_function():
```

You'd use:

```
@decorator_factory(arg1, arg2)
def decorated_function():
```

and that call would return the actual decorator used.

This is commonly achieved by nesting the decorator inside another function, and using the arguments of that new outer function to adjust the behaviour of the decorator returned.

For your sample decorator, indent your decorator (you probably want to rename it to reduce confusion) and wrap it in a factory function that takes the `logging` argument:

```
def before_run(logging=True):
    def decorator(func):
        print "hello from before run"
        def handle_arg(a,b):
            if(a>0):
                if logging:
                    print "Altering argument a to 100"
                a = 100
            return func(a,b)

        return handle_arg

    return decorator
```

I renamed your original `before_run()` decorator function to `decorator` to make it clear that that is the decorator being produced by the factory. It is returned at the end; this decorator function uses `logging` as a closure to switch logging on or off.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of confusion indeed with decorators in python.

This is due to the fact that:

- a decorator with arguments is not actually a decorator but a
  *decorator factory*, as noted by others. So to implement a decorator
  that can be called without and with arguments, it is a bit tricky.
- people tend to think that decorators are necessarily function wrappers, like in your example. But that's not the case: a decorator can entirely replace the decorated function or class by something else (not even a function or class!).

To ease decorator development I wrote [decopatch](https://smarie.github.io/python-decopatch/). With it you do not have to care: your decorators handle both no-parenthesis and with-parenthesis calls correctly.

It supports two development styles: **nested** (like in python decorator factories) and **flat** (one less level of nesting). This is how your example would be implemented in *flat* mode:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from decopatch import function_decorator, DECORATED
from makefun import wraps

@function_decorator
def before_run(func=DECORATED):
    # (1) create a signature-preserving wrapper
    @wraps(func)
    def _func_wrapper(*f_args, **f_kwargs):
        print("hello from before run")
        if f_kwargs['a'] > 0:
            f_kwargs['a'] = 100
        return func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)

    # (2) return it
    return _func_wrapper
```

Finally it supports an additional development style, that I call **double-flat**, that is dedicated to creating signature-preserving function wrappers. Your example would be implemented like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from decopatch import function_decorator, WRAPPED, F_ARGS, F_KWARGS

@function_decorator
def before_run(func=WRAPPED, f_args=F_ARGS, f_kwargs=F_KWARGS):
    # this is directly the signature-preserving wrapper body
    print("hello from before run")
    if f_kwargs['a'] > 0:
        f_kwargs['a'] = 100
    return func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
```

In both cases you can check that it runs correctly:

```
@before_run
def running_func(a, b):
    print("a", a, "b", b)
    return a + b

assert running_func(-1, 2) == 1
assert running_func(1, 2) == 102
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-decopatch/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a decorator factory if you want your decorator's behavior to be controlled dynamically via parameters (just like with any regular function). For example, say I want a decorator that prints a message before calling a function. I could do something like:

```
# Our decorator:
def print_message_decorator(func):
    # The wrapper (what we replace our decorated function with):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('A function is being called.')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

@print_message_decorator
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

@print_message_decorator
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b
```

Now if I call `add` or `subtract` each will print `A function is being called.`

Now say, however, that I actually want the decorator to be dynamically generated, and I want to be able to customize the message that is printed out per decorated function. I solve this by making my decorator a decorator factory instead.

```
# Our decorator factory:
def print_message_decorator_factory(msg):
    # The decorator it creates:
    def print_message_decorator(func):
        # The wrapper (what we replace our decorated function with):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(msg)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return print_message_decorator

@print_message_decorator_factory('Calling the add function.')
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

@print_message_decorator_factory('Calling the subtract function.')
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b
```

Now if I call `add` it prints `Calling the add function.` and if I call `subtract` it prints `Calling the subtract function.`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.